# Splitting strings return by awk in PHP

Tags: php, awk

I have the following PHP code snippet to run awk. It returns the right record entries. However, I cannot extract the individual fields from each of the record using PHP? I tried preg_split with " " delimiter but, it did not output anything. Thanks.

```
$cmd = "/usr/bin/awk '{if($1 >= \"$s_period\" && $1 <= \"$e_period\"){print $1,$2}}' File_Path";
exec($cmd,$output);

foreach ($output as $result)
{
      $temp = preg_split(" ",$result);
      echo "$temp[0]\t$temp[1]<br />";  //no output
}
```

The input file is in format: 2013-04-03(date) 67788.7(val1) 4555(val2) 5555(val3) 
$output contains record as "2013-04-03 67788.7". That is, date followed by stats

Comment: Please post a snippet of the $output array and the string contained in `$output[1]`

Comment: you could replace the awk with php

Comment: Can you post the output of `print_r($output)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$output contains record as "2013-07-15 6361.97". That is, date followed by stats
```

To split your `$output` string into an array:

```
$temp = explode(" ", $output);
```

To output the individual bits:

```
echo "{$temp[0]}\t{$temp[1]}<br />";
```

Comment: that worked, should have thought of explode. Any reason why preg_split did not?

Comment: You can't iterate over a string using `foreach`. You probably tried to split an empty string `$result`, assuming it even hit that line of code. You needed to split the `$output` string.